# MailCore2 on Apple Watch

Tags: mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, apple-watch, mailcore2

I have created an app for the iPhone and iPad less than a month ago that uses MailCore2 to send emails without the use of a dialog box (like the one MFMailComposeViewController uses).

The app works great and based on reviews, the implementation of MailCore2 provides a sense of security to users when sending messages.

I am in the middle of creating the same app on the Apple Watch itself, and was wondering if implementation of MailCore2 was possible on this device.  If so, can a link be attached so I could see how to implement this into my project?  If this can't be implemented, are there other third party solutions for sending emails without a dialog box on the Apple Watch?

Thanks in advance to all who answer.

Comment: I haven't tried. Could you let me know if it works for you?

Comment: To be honest, MailCore2 doesn't perform properly when tested by Apple. All MailCore2 is made for is iOS and OS X. I don't believe that the Apple Watch falls under either of these categories. I'll still search for solutions though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked in a while but I was under the impression that no code actually gets executed on the Watch. You do all processing on the device and then send your results to the Watch via an extension (like the Today extensions in notification centre). The Watch only stores the UI and doesn't execute any code. In this case, as everything would still be done on the phone, I don't see why MailCore wouldn't work or would work differently.

Maybe they've changed the SDK since I last looked though and code is now executable on the Watch?